# Suggestion Webservices

Tags: android, vb.net

**hello friends,**

I want to load `image`,`.swf file`,`video(flv,mp4)` in android.
For this i want to make webservices in vb.net and make Database.

1. so which `data-type` you suggest for .net for this each entity?
2. at android side, `SAX-parser` is comfortable?
3. load huge amount of Data so is there any `memory problem are raise`?
4. precaution to fetch this all entity.

**Thanks

nik**

Comment: can you give me reason why i am not use Vb

Comment: @Sayem Nonsense. If you can’t contribute then don’t.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph i also agree with you